# YouTube Android Player API - SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED - Android

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

YouTube Android Player API was released at [Google I/O 2013](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=fhWaJi1Hsfo).

I'm using it to create a Demo Project to play a video on Youtube.

My Demo Project worked fine on Android 4.0.4 and 4.1.

But it doesn't work on Android 2.2

I'm showing error inside this function :

```
@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,
        YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error : " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();

}
```

And I got :

```
Error : SERVICE VERSION UPDATE REQUIRED
```

Plz help. Many thanks.

---

UPDATE :

Thank for @Selvin : Note: Users need to run version 4.2.16 of the mobile YouTube app (or higher) to use the API.

On Android 2.2, my YouTube app version is lower than 4.2.16. Thank for helping.

Comment: `Note: Users need to run version 4.2.16 of the mobile YouTube app (or higher) to use the API.`

Comment: Yaaaaaa. On Android 2.2 , my YouTube app version is less than 4.2.16. Thank. You make my day.